# How after building the dist folder in Webpack, getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Error: bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I am using webpack to build for the production.

Can somebody here please check and help in understand what is wrong? The format for HTML is correct but seems like something is wrong while bundling.

Comment: Did you visit `/dist/bundle.js` to see what it is?

Comment: I checked from the dev tool and its shows error

Comment: You should visit `/dist/bundle.js` with your browser to see if it really is a Javascript file. This error is usually there because the path is showing an HTML / XML instead of a Javascript file. You build / development setup could have failed you. (No javascript should start with a `<`)

Comment: Thats a file created after the build.

Comment: It should have been there. But is it really there? You need to check with your browser. You could have got the routing wrong. Or your development setup might fail.

Comment: The file is there. checked in the browser.

Comment: Do you see a `<` at the beginning of your `/dist/bundle.js`? If not, you're looking at the wrong path.

Comment: Nope,  there is no `<` at the beginning

Comment: Are you hosting the files in your local machine? Or are you hosting it elsewhere?

Comment: I am using docker with nginx to host the files. Some how when I run it on my local then it works fine.

Comment: What URL address are you using to access the website in your docker?

Comment: I am appending the context path for instance `/test/ ` to the url.

Comment: If you're accessing your docker with `http://localhost:8080/`, then you should see the javascript at `http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js`. The local build result is not relevant to the docker's content, thus the files in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should visit `/dist/bundle.js` with your browser to see if it really is a Javascript file. This error is usually there because the path is showing an HTML / XML instead of a Javascript file. You build / development setup could have failed you.

No javascript should start with a `<`, but its common for HTML / XML.